# Time Machine sharing external hard drive with windows

Tags: time-machine

Is it possible to backup both Windows 7 and Mac OS X to the same Time Machine?

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine uses the *Mac OS Extended* file system whereas Windows is using *NTFS* or *FAT*.

If you want to use the same hard disc for backuping both operating systems, I would advise you to partition your hard disc, so that you are able to format both partitions with a different filesystem (one for OS X, one for Windows).
You can do this from OS X using the *disk utility* tool (system prefs).
[image: Disk Utility]

Format one hard disk with MAC OS Extended (Journaled) and one with FAT (or NTFS directly within Windows).

Now you are able to use the hard disk for backing up both operating systems.

Comment: Leave it Mac Journaled (HFS+) and it still is available via Windows. Or add an external Fat32 formatted hard drive via USB and it will work too.